# Linear dependence of solution components to ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ nonsingular real matrix, and let $y\colon \mathbb R_+\to \mathbb R^n$ be the solution of the ODE
$$
y'(t) =Ay(t)+v, \quad y(0)=0\in\mathbb R^n, 
$$
for a constant vector $v \in \mathbb R^n$. Clearly,
$$
y(t)=\left(e^{At}-I\right)A^{-1}v
$$
is a solution of the ODE. Denoting $y(t)=(y_1(t),y_2(t),\ldots,y_n(t))$, under which conditions on the matrix $A$ and the vector $v$ are the components of $y$ linearly dependent? That is, when does there exist $\beta=(\beta_1,\beta_2,\ldots,\beta_n)\in\mathbb R^n$ such that
$$
0=\sum_{i=1}^n\beta_iy_i(t),
$$
is satisfied?

I suspect the Wronskian to play a role here, but cannot clarify this myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start by showing that
$$ y_i(t) \text{ l.d.} \iff \exists \beta\in \mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\} \text{ such that} \beta^T A^kv = 0, \forall k \in \{0, n - 1\}$$
$\boxed\Longrightarrow$
From your solution, the condition is equivalent to
$$\beta^T (e^{At} - I) A^{-1}v = 0.$$
If we differentiate and make $t = 0$ we obtain
$$\beta^T v = 0.$$
Similarly, if we differentiate twice and replace $t = 0$, we have
$$\beta^T A v = 0.$$
If we continue we have that
$$\beta^T A^k v = 0 \quad \forall k\in\{0, n - 1\}.$$
$\boxed\Longleftarrow$
Conversely, if the previous equation is satisfied, then by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem we know that higher powers of $A$ can be writen as linear conbinations of the powers in $\{0, n - 1\}$, so we have
$$\beta^T A^k v = 0 \quad \forall k\in\mathbb N,$$
hence for any analytical function $f(A)$,
$$\beta^T f(A) v = 0 \quad \forall k\in\mathbb N,$$
in particular
$$\beta^T (e^{At} - I) A^{-1}v = 0.$$
(notice that by Cayley-Hamilton you can also write $A^{-1}$ as a finite sum of powers of $A$).

With all of this we conclude that your condition is equivalent to
$$ y_i(t) \text{ l.d.} \iff \dim[v, Av, \cdots, A^{n - 1} v]^\perp > 0$$
where $[v, Av, \cdots, A^{n - 1} v]$ is the space generated by the columns of $v, Av, \cdots, A^{n - 1}v$.

By the rank nullity theorem this is equivalent to the rank condition
$$ y_i(t) \text{ l.d.} \iff \operatorname{rank}[v, Av, \cdots, A^{n - 1} v] < n.$$

In control theory the opposite of this condition (namely that the matrix is full rank) is known as  the Kalman
rank condition. If you look in the literature you'll find several equivalent conditions to this one, although in practice, Kalman condition is the simplest to verify.